# pyodbc Incorrect syntax near '-'. (102)

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am trying to select all data from table that contains "-" dash symbol, and i get error

```
    cursor.execute(qStr)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '-'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

This is code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.2.100\name;DATABASE=base;UID=user;PWD=pass')

try:
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
except e:
    if e.__class__ == pyodbc.ProgrammingError:        
        conn == reinit()
        cursor = conn.cursor()

def checkIfEmpty (tableName):
    qStr = 'SELECT * FROM [' + tableName + ']'
    print(qStr)
    cursor.execute(qStr)
    asd=cursor.fetchone()
    if asd==None:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It prints out correct SQL statement `SELECT * FROM [Table-Name]` and in Microsoft SQL Management Studio this query works just fine with copy paste, but it wont work from python console

Same thing is with:`qStr = 'SELECT * FROM "' + tableName + '"`

Why is this happening, how can i get around it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using Brackets wherever there is dash.

```
qStr = "SELECT * FROM [{}]".format(tableName)
```

Comment: I've used [ ] just to try with it, same as "

Your suggestion don't work, same error:
`>>> checkIfEmpty("table-Name")
SELECT * FROM table-Name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    checkIfEmpty("table-Name")
  File "C:\Users\...
    cursor.execute(qStr)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '-'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

Comment: I am not sure if  "table-Name"  is valid. please change it to some better name like table_name or something if in your control. I think the problem is with '-' in your table name.

Comment: I can't change that, there are several tables in DB with dash in name "table-name" is example, i have table with "tab-le-name" format (2 dashes). Database have over 400 tables

Comment: Then you need to use `[]` around everywhere where dash comes. See edits

Answer (score 0):

Now you can also write it like this:

```
qStr = f"SELECT * FROM [{tableName}]"
```